# How to have bookmarks show up above autocompletion suggestions on Chrome's search bar?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a bunch of bookmarks saved for the reason of convenience and efficiency. However, whenever I type in Chrome's search bar, I see autocompleted suggestions first, then I see my bookmarks. Is there any way to get the bookmarks above the autocompletions?